# Pandas TypeError: data type "" not understood

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read the prepared data into Pandas. First of all, for non-numeric variables such as objects, the pandas describe method will give the variables:'number of non-empty values', 'number of unique values', 'number of maximum frequency variables', ' Maximum frequency'. In order to observe the missing situation intuitively, 'proportion of missing values' is added at the end. The code here has the problem in the title above.

```py
import pandas as pd

lcvs=[]   
lcvs.append(pd.read_csv('E:/chenln/Documents/python/ch3/project/LoanStats_2017Q3.csv',skiprows=0,header=1))
lcvs.append(pd.read_csv('E:/chenln/Documents/python/ch3/project/LoanStats_2017Q4.csv',skiprows=1))
lcvs.append(pd.read_csv('E:/chenln/Documents/python/ch3/project/LoanStats_2018Q1.csv',skiprows=1))
file=pd.concat(lcvs)
#三季度合并的文件写入到prj.csv
file.to_csv('E:/chenln/Documents/python/ch3/project/prj.csv',index=False)

data=pd.read_csv('E:/chenln/Documents/python/ch3/project/prj.csv',encoding="ISO-8859-1")

data.info()
#共有145个变量，38个是object类型

data.select_dtypes(include=['O']).describe().T.assign(missing_pct=data.apply(lambda x : (len(x)-x.count())/len(x)))
```

The specific information of the bug is :

```
>TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-8a0448befedd> in <module> <>
----> 1 data.select_dtypes(include=['0']).describe().T\
      2     .assign(missing_pct=data.apply(lambda x : (len(x)-x.count())/len(x)))
```

Thank you for your kind help!

If you want to browse all code information, please visit the following website：
https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/48504956

Comment: I've see a problem like this before, since you have only one value to include, let's remove the brackets creating a list and use scalar value (instead of a list with one element).  Try `data.select_dtypes(include='object')....`

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I think your advice is good, and I make a try on this code, but it still shows the following error: -> TypeError: data type "" not understood